# Replace carriage return (^M which appear by type CTRL+V) with sed in bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I'm trying to manage a file .xlsx in bash with a format of csv.

I do convert the excell the file (.xlsx) to .csv (CSV UTF-8(comma delimited)) to start managing the columns.

However, i notice in the excell file(.xlsx) the information contains in the cells of a column newlines(\n).

Could you help to solve this issue?

[The way it look at vim the converted file from xlsx to csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMsbA.png)

[The information it's not shown properly due to a problems in the segmentation of columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUIbu.png)

In the image before the command that I apply is: cat file | awk -F '|' '{print $2"|"$7"|"$27"|"$29"|"$30"|"$31}'

- I do think in a solution by going into a use of sed to eliminate the \n with the following command:
  sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file
  [How can I replace each newline (\n) with a space using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-each-newline-n-with-a-space-using-sed)
  And then I could substitute the carriage return (^M) (e.g.| sed -e 's/^M/\n/g') to manage properly each column with awk(e.g. input | awk -F '|' '{print $2"|"$7"|"$27"|"$29"|"$30"|"$31}')

  However, the solution I think do not work because by applying the first sed command all the information stay in the same line and then I could not manage it with the awk command.

Have you thought of another solution?

[The csv file after applying sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv6jc.png)

My expectation is to be as shown here
[The info of each line be with \n to be able to manage with awk each column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T61E.png) 
[The result I expect is as shown here by applying the awk command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imNQl.png)

Comment: Replace all of the links and images in your question with text so we can a) see it, and b) help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your input, output, and code as Code Blocks, and run `cat -A` or similar on your input/output files to show where the CRs and LFs actually appear (CSV export from XLS is usually LF alone inside fields and CR-LF at the end of records, `"this","foo\nbar","that"\r\n`)

Comment: Also see [whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Comma-Separated-Fields (the latter for info on gawks new CSV-handling mode).

Comment: I jsut noticed you said you're using `awk -F '|'` - `CSV` stands for Comma-Separated-Values so the fields are separated by `,`s, not by `|`s. If you want the output to be separated by `|`s then you'd set the `OFS`, not the `FS` (as set by `-F`) but you probably also need to sanitize your values to handle existing `|`s within [unquoted] fields.

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? Parsing CSV can be tricky (for instance, when a field contains the field separator itself, or a literal double quote). Why don't you use a CSV parser for this, which already takes care of these details?

Comment: Just curious - you said `I do convert the excell the file (.xlsx) to .csv (CSV UTF-8(comma delimited))` but now that I can see the images you posted (**please** only post text in future - no images or links) I see your files really are `|`-separated instead of `,`-separated, as your script suggested you were trying to parse with `-F'|'` and I thought was a bug. Using `|`-separated input makes things harder as it's a regexp metachar so you have to be careful how you use it, there are no specs for it, and it doesn't have any benefits over `,` so - what are you really doing and why?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV export from XLS is usually LF alone inside fields and CR-LF at the end of records, i.e. it looks like:

```
$ cat -A file
"this","foo$
""bar,bar""$
here","that"^M$
"stuff","nonsense$
here","too"^M$
```

which is actually just 2 records but some fields contain LFs (`$` above). CRs are displayed as `^M` above.

Given that format of input, to convert the CR-LFs at the end of lines to LFs and convert any LFs within quoted fields to blanks (just removing them would corrupt the remaining text), this would work using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\"" }
    {
        $0 = prev sep $0
        prev = $0
        sep = ORS
    }
    NF%2 {
        sub(/\r$/,"")
        for ( i=2; i<NF; i+=2 ) {
            gsub(/\n/," ",$i)
        }
        print
        prev = sep = ""
    }
' file
"this","foo ""bar,bar"" here","that"
"stuff","nonsense here","too"
```

Note that although the input contains CR-LF at the end of each record we can't rely on awk seeing that as the underlying platform's C primitives may strip those CRs before awk sees them. In GNU awk you can get around that problem by setting `BINMODE=3` but that's not portable to other awks.

See [What's the most robust way to efficiently parse CSV using awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk) for more information on parsing CSVs with awk.

Comment: Thanks! Your resolved perfectly my problem. At the moment I do not understand how it works but I'm going to depht on it.

Comment: You're welcome but since your input file isn't actually CSV my script may be doing things that don't need to be done, or not doing things that do need to be done, for whatever constraints your `|`-separated input file has.